# Undefined property: Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator::$images

Tags: php, laravel, thumbnails

i tried to display the images of a tinghirs table images field but pity it gives me error `Undefined property: Illuminate \ Pagination \ LengthAwarePaginator :: $ images`

**TinghirsController.php**

```
public function index()
    {
       $tinghirs=Tinghir::paginate(48);
       return view('tinghirs.index', ['tinghirs' => $tinghirs]);
    }
```

**index.php**

```
<div class="row mix-grid thumbnails">
                            @if ($tinghirs->images)
                            @foreach (json_decode($tinghirs->images, true) as $images)
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 mix cat_nature cat_all">
                                <a class="thumbnail-item">
                                    <img src="{{ Voyager::image($images) }}" style="width:600px;height:400px">
                                    <div class="thumbnail-info">
                                        <p>Curabitur ut lorem id tellus malesuada tincidunt et eget purus</p>
                                        <button class="btn btn-primary"><span class="fa fa-link"></span></button>
                                        <button class="btn btn-primary"><span class="fa fa-eye"></span></button>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            @endforeach
                            @endif
                    </div>
```

Comment: You need to loop your pagination... `@if ($tinghirs->images)` is not valid. Something like `@foreach($tinghirs as $tinghir)`, then `@if($tinghir->images)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64075355/property-images-does-not-exist-on-this-collection-instance-using-laravel-6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You return a paginator object, you either have to call `items()` on it or iterate through it.

I would imagine the code could look similar to this. The way you use json decode seems super weird and you are probably doing something wrong.

```
@foreach(($tinghirs as $tinghir)
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 mix cat_nature cat_all">
        <a class="thumbnail-item">
            <img src="{{ Voyager::image($tinghir->images) }}" style="width:600px;height:400px">
            <div class="thumbnail-info">
            <p>Curabitur ut lorem id tellus malesuada tincidunt et eget purus</p>
            <button class="btn btn-primary"><span class="fa fa-link"></span>                 </button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary"><span class="fa fa-eye"></span></button>
        </a>
    </div>
@endforeach
```